# Android Tv button is not selected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tv, smart-tv

I encountered a problem with the display layout.
Relativelayout @+id/media is not visible when you put visible. He remains under Relativelayout @+id/media2,is selectable from dpad but remains under the other.

if the parts and put media2 first and second media. When media is visible, but can not be selectable dpad.

there is a certain order to make the media though is written first be above the media2?
Thank you

layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_video_box"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/media"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:background="#e72a2a"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Back"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Play"
                android:id="@+id/button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Next"
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/app_video_seekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relativeLayout" />


    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/media2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <tcking.github.com.giraffeplayer.IjkVideoView
            android:id="@+id/video_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you need to specify relative positions for media and media2, just like you have done for other controls.

Comment: can you give me more details to?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to control the focus on different items on screen. You can use XML tags specifically for this:

`android:nextFocusForward="@+id/media2"`

`android:nextFocusDown="@+id/media2"`

You can look at the [docs for keyboard navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/navigation.html) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

In Android TV, only ui elements gets selected only if they are focusable.
Achieve this either through xml attributes or by code.

```
view.setFocusable(true)
```

or

```
android:focusable="true".
```

And set rules for each ui elements to whom the focus to be transferred.

```
android:nextFocus{direction}="view_id".
```

where direction could be *down, top, right or left*.

focusable items